# how to add a key in python from user input

Tags: python

example :
 needed user input as key to be added :  32inchTV
    this TV has a sub description of the following
     price : 5000
     weight : 5kgs
     features: HDMI
     features2: USB movie

I want to add that key to my dictionary, it's like a dictionary that will point to a list in which I can also edit the sub descriptions in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What code have you tried so far? Edit your question with your code and we can take a look.

Comment: You seem to have never used a dictionary so I would recommend reading [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm). If you understand it then you will be able to answer to your own question. As a side note this might be better suited as a class than a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to have a lot of tv attributes then a class will be better suited for your needs than a dictionary. It will be easier to access than a dictionary of lists. You will still use a dictionary to store the `TV` class objects though.

```
class TV():
    def __init__(self, name, size, weight, plugs):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.weight = weight
        self.plugs = plugs

d = {}
tv_name = raw_input('TV: ')
size = raw_input('Size: ')
weight = raw_input('Weight: ')
plugs=[]
plug = raw_input('Plug: ')
while plug:
    plugs.append(plug)
    plug = raw_input('Plug: ')

d[tv_name] = TV(tv_name,size,weight,plugs)
tv = d[tv_name]
print tv.name
print tv.size
print tv.weight
print tv.plugs

TV: Samsung
Size: 32
Weight: 50 kgs
Plug: 3 usb
Plug: 2 HDMI
Plug: 
Samsung
32
50 kgs
['3 usb', '2 HDMI']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but nonsense. This is the code, however, you should really choose another way

```
k = input("Please input something") # e.g. test
dict = {}
dict[k] = "This is my input"
print(dict) # prints {'test': 'This is my  input'}
```

Again, this is bad :-)